# Show image textures in 'material' or 'texture' shading modes in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, 3d-view

I've created a material that uses an image as a texture, applied it to a plane and then UV-unwrapped the plane.

The texture shows up in the final render, even in the 'rendered' shading mode of the viewport, but not in 'texture' or 'material' modes.

Everything seems right from what i've checked in multiple questions and tuts... but it still the plane shows like a giant black square.

I would appreciate any hints on the problem.

[image]

here is the .blend if you wanna try [.blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33311)

Comment: Blend works fine for me.. Try selecting the texture node though. In *textured view* the last selected texture node is used (though I don't think this should matter when there is only one). Perhaps it's a GPU specific issue?

Comment: I think it may be something like that... what does GPU stands for?... I am using a macbook pro and i think it uses an integrated graphics card :/ ... maybe the image for the texture is too big?

Comment: @invicente Then it wouldn't render...

Comment: Okay, the only reason it should work on mine and not on yours is that i inserted a different picture. Try re-uploading yours into your node or try a different picture. GPU stands for Graphics Processing Unit.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about hardware issues/a bug.

Comment: Yeah guys, it's something about the picture i used. maybe it's too big. i changed it for one of standar res and it worked fine. Thanks! @GiantCowFilms, you may be right... what should i do with the question?

Comment: @invicente delete it.

Comment: BTW, try using the same image resized, or saved as a different format. That might fix the issue.

Comment: C#22  Hopefully this was not too hard to find.  Decoder gold can be found here. http://i.stack.imgur.com/PXtQK.png and C#23 can be found here http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/17777/5426 good luck :-)